# Routing Redirect Goes to Wrong Action - View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`rails 6.1.4 -- ruby 2.6.7p197`

I have a small app I'm developing. So far it has a form that, when submitted, goes to the `controller#create` method.  When the record is `created` a `redirect_to` to a `thank_you` method happens.  The `redirect_to` is not working.  It is actually redirecting to the `show` method.  I am "assuming" it is a routing issue, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I could use some help in figuring out why the `redirect_to` is going to `show` not `thank_you`.

```
EDIT in response to suggestion by @Vishal Jain below:

I've tried these in the redirect_to:

redirect_to(living_muay_thai_survey_pain_points_thank_you_path)
redirect_to(living_muay_thai_survey_pain_points_thank_you_url)

They both still take me to the show action/view.
```

```
Controller:

class LivingMuayThai::SurveyPainPointsController < ApplicationController
  layout "living_muay_thai"

  def index
  end

  def new
    @survey_pain_point = LivingMuayThai::SurveyPainPoint.new
  end

  def create
    pain_point = LivingMuayThai::SurveyPainPoint.new(pain_point_params)

    if pain_point.save
      flash[:notice]="Your survey has been submitted"
      redirect_to(action: "thank_you")
    else
      flash[:notice]="Sorry, your survey could not be saved."
      render
    end
  end

  def thank_you
  end

  def show
  end

  ...

end

-----------------------------

Routes:

namespace :living_muay_thai do
    resources :survey_pain_points do 
      collection do
        get  :search
        post :search
      end
    end
  end
  get  'living_muay_thai/survey_pain_points/thank_you'
  post 'living_muay_thai/survey_pain_points/thank_you'
...


routes in command line for thank_you and show.

living_muay_thai_survey_pain_points_thank_you GET    /living_muay_thai/survey_pain_points/thank_you(.:format)                                          living_muay_thai/survey_pain_points#thank_you

living_muay_thai_survey_pain_point GET    /living_muay_thai/survey_pain_points/:id(.:format)                                                living_muay_thai/survey_pain_points#show
```

I added the thank_you action and view so users would not go to the index view.  They don't need to see all survey records.  I added the route for `thank_you` outside of `namespace` and `resources` cuz I could not get it to work inside of those.

I see the `thank_you` route is plural `...pain_points...` and the show is singular `...pain_point...`  I tried to make the `thank_you`  route singular, but that does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try adding redirect_to `living_muay_thai_survey_pain_points_thank_you_url`?

Comment: I tried a similar one: ```living_muay_thai_survey_pain_points_thank_you_path```

Comment: ```living_muay_thai_survey_pain_points_thank_you_url``` also takes me to the ```show``` action/view.  strange.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  After staring at it for an hour and trying different things, I remembered some rule I read years ago that the order the routes are in matters: `First one that fits the route needed is used (or similar)`.  So, I moved the `thank_you` route up to be before the namespaced block, just to try it...:

```
get 'living_muay_thai/survey_pain_points/thank_you'
namespace :living_muay_thai do
  resources :survey_pain_points do 
  end
end
```

and ta-da!!, it works correctly now.  Still not sure why the `show` was seen as fitting for the `thank_you` action, but I'm sure it will come to me when I'm not thinking on it.

Thanks for looking.